# How to get values from a loop defined in Knockout JS UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have two arrays : `Schedules` and `ControllerDoors` and the values come from a **Controller.**

The **ViewModel** looks like :

```
    getAddDetails: function (siteId) {
        var SiteId = siteId;
        this.postDataRequest('/GetAddDetails', { Id: SiteId }, function (err, result) {
            if (!err && result && result.success) {
                debugger;

                var scheduleData = result.data1;
                var controllerDoorData = result.data2;

                this.AddModel.Schedules(scheduleData);


                this.AddModel.ControllerDoors(_.map(controllerDoorData || [], function (item) {

                    return new ISP.AddPanelModel(item);
                }));
```

And in **Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [NoCache]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetAddDetails (string Id)
    {
        try
        {

            var scheduleList = new[] 
            {
                new { ScheduleId = "Schedule1",ScheduleName = "Always On" },
                new { ScheduleId = "Schedule2",ScheduleName = "Never On"}
            };

            var doorsForSite = new[]
                {
                new { ControllerId ="controller1",ControllerName="Eagle",IsChecked = "false",
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId="Door1",DoorName="DoorOne"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door2", DoorName = "DoorTwo" }
                        }

                    },
                new { ControllerId ="controller2",ControllerName="NetAxis",IsChecked = "false",
                        Doors = new[]
                        {
                            new { DoorId=  "Door3",DoorName="DoorThree"},
                            new { DoorId = "Door4", DoorName = "DoorFour" },
                            new { DoorId = "Door5", DoorName = "DoorFive" }
                        }

                    }
            };


            return Json(new { success = true, data1 = scheduleList, data2 = doorsForSite }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, errorMessage = System.Web.Helpers.Resources.General_error });
        }
    }
```

So **effectively** , each `ControllerDoor` array item will have `Doors` array inside and `Schedules` is a separate array.

But in UI , I need to populate the `schedule` dropdown for each door and on press of `Save` , I need each one of the `Schedule` Values corresponding to each door.

**UI**

```
<ul class="accgrouptableaccordian scroll-x scroll-y">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data.AddModel.ControllerDoors -->
    <li>
        <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <span>
                            <span>
                                <span class="ispicon ispicon_accordian_droparrow">
                                </span>
                                <span class="title" style="line-height:20px;" data-bind="text: ControllerName() + ' - ' + Doors().length + ' Doors'">
                                </span>
                            </span>
                            <span>

                            </span>
                        </span>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive panel-body">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tbody data-bind="foreach:Doors">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div>
                                                <span data-bind="text:DoorId"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="col-md-4">

                                            <select name="drpSchedulesAccess" class="form-control drpSchedulesAccess" data-bind="options:$root.AddModel.Schedules,
                                                optionsText: 'ScheduleName',
                                                optionsValue: 'ScheduleId',
                                                value: $data.ScheduleId"></select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

[image]

**But this is the problem.**

`Schedule` is a separate array and in UI it seems `each door can have it's own schedule`.

But if I do `this.AddModel.Schedules` , I only get the two values.

**I need to get the five `Schedule` values corresponding to five doors displayed.**

How to do it ? Please help.

Comment: so how are you tying the selected schedule to the door?  is this correct your model is something like function door(doorId, doorName){
var self = this;
this.doorId = ko.observable(doorId);
this.doorName = ko.observable(doorName);
}   function schedule(scheduleId, scheduleName){
var self = this;
this.scheduleId = ko.observable(scheduleId);
this.scheduleName = ko.observable(scheduleName);
}  don't you also need in doors something like this.selectedScheduleId  I could not format my comment well so is this what your set up looks like? http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32404/

Comment: Can you provide a sample Jsfiddle of your question?